# Can we get more votes when rep hits a cetain level?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, voting, voting-limits

I just ran out of votes :( There are alot of good questions out there and some not so good ones.

I'd love it if we had thresholds were we got more votes based on rep. Possible?

Comment: Ironically, I'm out of votes today or I'd certainly vote this up.  (Sincerely)

Comment: More deletion, close, spam and offensive votes too please!

Answer (score 11):

Doubtful; we limit daily votes for 3 reasons

1. So casting a vote has more intrinsic value, as you have a limited number to cast. Make each one count, rather than casting them willy-nilly.
2. Because we believe too much participation can become a mild negative -- sure, enjoy our sites, but enjoy your job and life more! There's always more votes tomorrow.
3. Anything that isn't rate limited, in our experience, will be abused eventually.

Comment: big +1 on the "enjoy your life more" part. Sites like this can easily become addictive, and it's seriously refreshing to see one where that's seen as a bad thing.

Comment: 2. is a very sane and fine point. But is the number of available *votes* really the area in which excessive participation should be discouraged? Every downvote one can't cast means that some piece of crap survives a little while longer. I feel quality control is the one thing that one shouldn't be left unable to do any time of the day. Is increasing the number of votes and close votes really no option at all?

Comment: @pekka use flags in that case; I doubt this would cause more voting on *questions* which is what is really needed. More votes on answers is useless from my perspective.

Comment: well, I could use more, and I'd be happy if they were for questions only. I ran out of votes around 1300 GMT today. *So many crappy questions, so few votes...*

Comment: @pekka this is what flags are for, by definition .. and as you get more flag weight guess what you get? yep, *more flags to use*

Answer (score 1):

Possible, yes. Likely? No.

Still... I think it's a good idea.